Cutting a Mesh with a Plane Using Shader Graph in Unity
I'm working on a project in Unity and need to cut a mesh using a plane as a reference, similar to what is shown in this video. I would like to achieve this effect using Shader Graph and Unity, and preferably without changing the material of my mesh since it's a combination of multiple parts. Is this doable? If so, how can I go about it?
I'm new to shaders, so any detailed guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The link is broken. Please provide a valid link, or describe the expected result.
